Cannot find symbol error after while statement in my do-while loop
I am not sure where I went wrong with my do while loop can anyone help me understand this error I am getting
Here is my java code:
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double sum;
    double average;
    double count;
    double largest;
    double smallest;
    
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter a grade or enter a negative number to stop:");
        double grade=input.nextDouble();
        sum+=grade;
        
    }while(grade>0);
        
    
    System.out.println("The sum is"+sum);
    }
}

Here is he error:
Main.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    }while(grade>0);
           ^
  symbol:   variable grade
  location: class Main
1 error

I not really sure at all where I went wrong. I am new to java.
